# Find F'(x) for the following F(x)

Tags: real-analysis, integration

$F{(x)}=\int_{0}^{x}{ f(t-x) dt}$

let $u=x-t$, then $du=dx$

Im confused about changing the values for the integrand, I don't quite understand why they change from 0 to x to -x to 0.

$F{(x)}=\int_{0}^{x}{ f(t-x) dt}=\int_{-x}^{0}{ f(u) du}$

I know how to continue from here with FTC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variable of integration is $t$. So if $u=t-x$ then $du=dt$.

Now the function $u(t)=t-x$ defined for $t\in[0,x]$ maps $[0,x]$ to $[0-x,x-x]$, so
$$\int_0^xf(t-x)dt=\int_{-x}^0f(u)du=-\int_0^{-x}f(u)du$$

To differentiate, you must apply FTC **and** the chain rule.

Answer (score 0):

According to what you typed in the post, the change-of-variable function is not suitable! It should be $t \mapsto t-x$. If $\phi: t \mapsto t-x$, then
$$
\int_{0}^{x} f(t-x) dt = \int_{0}^{x}f\circ \phi(t)dt = \int_{0}^{x}f\circ \phi(t)\phi'(t)dt = \int_{\phi(0)}^{\phi(x)} f(t) dt = \int_{-x}^{0}f(t)dt
$$
by change-of-variable theorem.